# SQL : Inserting multiple values in a single column

Tags: sql, mariadb

How can I save multiple values in my `roles` it should look like this :

[image]

I tried this query:

```
    export const insertIndividual = (data, result) => {
      db.query(
        "INSERT INTO individual (email, last_name, first_name, phone_number, password, 
suppress_email_sending, is_participant, org_id, suborgs, roles, created_at, modified_at, created_by, modified_by) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, [?], NOW(), NOW(), ?, ?)",
        [
          data.email,
          data.last_name,
          data.first_name,
          data.phone_number,
          data.password,
          data.suppress_email_sending,
          data.is_participant,
          data.org_id,
          data.suborgs,
          data.roles,
          data.created_by,
          data.modified_by,
        ],
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            result(err, null);
          } else {
            result(null, results);
          }
        }
      );
    };
```

But I am getting this error:

[image]

How can I solve error?

Comment: Why is the 10th parameter `[?]` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's for my data.roles, I am thinking to insert it as an array to my column but it doesn't work. Because I tried just putting `?` the values being passed returns this error :



  `sqlMessage: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",
  sql: "INSERT INTO individual (email, last_name, first_name, phone_number, password, suppress_email_sending, is_participant, org_id, suborgs, roles, created_at, modified_at, created_by, modified_by) VALUES ('latest.user@mail.com', 'user', 'latest', '090912321', '', 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, NOW(), NOW(), '1', '1')"   
}`

Comment: You _can't_ insert an array like that in a single insert statement.  You need multiple inserts.

Comment: MySQL does not have array column types, your field is either `VARCHAR`, `JSON` or something like that. You can check column type in your favourite MySQL client (HeidiSQL, MySQL Workbench...).

Comment: Said that, whoever designed roles that way surely finished earlier that afternoon at the cost of leaving some nice technical debt for the whole company ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the square brackets [].  What you need is data.roles.toString() or data.roles.join(",") to convert an array to a string with the format you want.

Comment: We can see `1, 3, 5` in the picture of the error message so either the JavaScript library takes care of that automatically or it's already a string.

Comment: If it is already a string, then you still don't need the square brackets, right?

Comment: About that... It's not about "needing". The syntax is totally made up, it triggers a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I just enclosed the value of roles with `'single quotes'`. Instead of `[?]`, I used `'?'`, is this a good approach, or does anyone has a better idea?

Comment: `'?'` can't possibly work. It isn't a place-holder, it's literal question mark. Did you verify the column data type as I suggested?